# Why is QGIS map not sharp when Printing it?

Tags: qgis, printing

This is my first project so please bear with me!

I have downloaded the OS StreetView Map and loaded it in to QGIS, the map is 1:10000.

I am running a 27" Mac, but when I view the map on screen at the scale of 1:10000 the details are not sharp. And they are even worse when i print them out.

Is there a step I have missed that somehow sharpens the image on screen - i.e. maybe I have it in some form of "Draft" mode to speed up the processing ?

The project is quite large and will take some time so I want to check that I will get a decent output once I have finished before I spend all of the time doing it.

Comment: Are you using the open layer plugin?

Comment: I was using whatever loaded with the original download. I just looked at the list of plugins and found the open layer plugin so I will try installing that and see if it makes any difference. Are there any others that i need ? @NathanW

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Open Layer plugin has issues, like alignment from my personal experience.  Perhaps resolution issues too.

Other possibilities:
1) QGIS looks blurry on my retina Macs in map and Print Composer views.  What is your exact iMac model info?  Mine is under About This Mac: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013).
2) That said, you might try also checking that you have DPI set to something decent (maybe 300 or so?) in Print Composer/Composition settings. Does it still look blurry?

Comment: Thanks for the reply my mac is iMac (27-inch, Late 2013), I just tried a simple test of opening the TiF file in the standard mac preview software and it opens really clearly, far clearer than QGIS. Looking at it now its not even clear prior to getting to the Print Composer screens. Is it possible to do anything about the plugin issue ? It can't just be me this is effecting ? - thanks

Comment: I don't believe it's just you.  Retina Mac displays don't look clear in QGIS... yet, though output from Print Composer does appear clear(er).  Apparently, a QT5 version of QGIS 2.8, which may help resolve the display issue, is available ([log notes](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog28/index.html#feature-qt5-support)) to build but not as an installable binary.